# How can I send data from child process to parent process using pipes for inter-process communication?

Tags: c, linux, pipe

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 



int main(void){
    
    int a[10], b[10], i;  
    
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        a[i] = rand() % 15; 
        b[i] = rand() % 10;  
    
    }
    
    int result1=0;
    int result2=0;
        if(fork() == 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                result2 += a[i]*b[i]; 
                                       }
                
                       } else { 
            for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++){
                result1 += a[i]*b[i];   
        }
        
    }
```

As you can see  I'm pretty new to OS.

**My question is**: how can the child process send the `result2` to the parent process so I can find the addition of result1 and result2? I'm supposed to be using pipes for inter-process communication.

I didn't upload the whole question since it will make it a long question.

Comment: So you know you should use pipes. What prevent you from trying it? Like searching around for documentation/usage examples?

Comment: You will need to open the pipe before you fork.  Your child process will need to write the result on the appropriate pipe file descriptor (and close unused end of the pipe, and close the used end once it is finished).  You parent process will need to close the unused end of the pipe and read the result from the used end and close it. That's the basics — anything discussing the use of pipes will outline more or less that information.  So, now you need to show us what you've tried.  There are ways to get it wrong.  They're fewer and further between for this scenario than many others.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm still trying tho, but I don't want to show you a code that doesn't work :]

Comment: @sayo — we expect to see code that doesn't work; it wouldn't be suitable for a question on SO if it did work (it would probably belong on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead).  But we do expect to see an honest attempt at solving the problem.  We won't write your homework for you.

Comment: [Hint]: In case you are still stuck, learn file I/O using `read()` and `write()` system calls since pipes are essentially files.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you I've been stuck in the pipe part so i just watched again. well I'm new to stack overflow thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just answer the missing parts

under the main I declared

```
int fb[2];
```

inside child process  (IF before the for loop)

```
close(fb[0]);
```

to send the result from child process to parent

```
write(fb[1],&result2,sizeof(int));
close(fb[1]);
```

inside the parent process:

```
int result3;
read(fb[0],&result3, sizeof(int));
close(fb[0]);
```

after finding the dot product

calculating the overall was pretty straight:

```
int oAll;
oAll=  (result3+result1) / 2;       
printf("%d", oAll);
```